# Java NoSuchElementException when using Scanner.next() for StreamIO

Tags: java, inputstream, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I am doing my first foray into StreamIO.  I have a text file (name is entered by user) that I am able to read fine using this code:

```
 Scanner inputStream = null;    
 **Prompt user for fileName, check if exists etc.**

 try {    
      inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
      inputOpen = 1;
 }
 catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
       System.out.println("Error opening the file " + fileName);
 }
 catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("Unkown errow with the file " + fileName);
 }

 while(inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
       String line = inputStream.nextLine();
       System.out.println(line);
 }
```

Per my assignment, I need to loop through input text in a file and ignore whitespace, then output it in lines of a certain length (set by user).  So I am using a while loop to go to EOF, getting the next word from the text, adding it to a line and testing that length.  If it fits, I add it the line, if it exceeds I print the current line and start the next.  So I am now using this:

```
 while(inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = null, lineTest = null;

        String word = inputStream.next();
        lineTest = (lineTest + " " + word);
        if (lineTest.length() > width) {
            outputStream.println(line);
            line = word;
        }
        else
            line = (line + " " + word);      
    }
```

And I am getting the NoSuchElementException for this line: String word = inputStream.next();

I don't really understand this exception very well to diagnose it.  From what it's like I'm trying to scan something that isn't there, like going past the EOF.  I think my while loop is correct, so what else would it be?

Comment: post input text file. If it's not online pastebin.com is at your disposal.

Comment: This loop could give errors if your last line was an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasNext` with `next`. Use `hasNextLine` with `nextLine`.

It is possible that there is a next line, but not a next word - for example, if the last line in the file is blank. Then `nextLine` would return the blank line, but `next` would throw an exception since there are no more words.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what [immibus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269514/4642801) said.
To add as example:

Imagine you ask for a int from keyboard input using nextInt()

The user enters the number '8' on a line. Athough the nextInt() will return the '8' the user entered, the new line character "\n" from the input was not read because that comes after the int.

There is an implicit "\n" after user input, and anything BUT nextLine() will pick up everything BUT "\n". So nextInt() will pick up the int, next() will pick up a word, and so forth.

So, if after you ask the user for some input OTHER THAN nextLine(), and then your next request anywhere else in the program is nextLine(), the nextLine() method will return the implicit "\n" from the last line the user entered (because this "\n" was never returned). I hope I'm making sense. Feels a little difficult to describe.

A concrete example:

```
int a = kb.nextInt();  //user enters the integer 8 and presses ENTER, creating a new line in the input stream which you must keep track of
String text = kb.nextLine(); //  user enters any string
```

int 'a' would store the integer 8 and 'text' would store simply "\n". This is because if you allow the user to press enter between statements (for example if you asked at different times) then the user input is literally : "8" + "\n" + "user input string" + "\n"

So the nextLine() after nextInt() will grab that "\n" after the 8 instead of the one after "user input string" !

To avoid this, I usually do:

```
int a = kb.nextInt();
kb.nextLine(); //simply grabs the "\n" after any integer is entered
String text = kb.nextLine()
```

This way you grab the line you were intending to get.

I used the user input example because it is more intuitive, but of course the same exact concept applies to text you parse from a text file using an object of the class Scanner. You tested the file for a hasNnextLine(), and it did have one; it could have simply have had:  "\n"  -> END OF FILE
So it had a nextLine(), but it didn't have a next(). That's the problem.

Sorry for a long answer to a relatively simple question.